# Apache spark dealing with case statements

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am dealing with transforming SQL code to PySpark code and came across some SQL statements. I don't know how to approach case statments in pyspark? I am planning on creating a RDD and then using rdd.map and then do some logic checks. Is that the right approach? Please help!

Basically I need to go through each line in the RDD or DF and based on some logic I need to edit one of the column values.

```
     case  
               when (e."a" Like 'a%' Or e."b" Like 'b%') 
                And e."aa"='BW' And cast(e."abc" as decimal(10,4))=75.0 Then 'callitA'

               when (e."a" Like 'b%' Or e."b" Like 'a%') 
                And e."aa"='AW' And cast(e."abc" as decimal(10,4))=75.0 Then 'callitB'

else

'CallitC'
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert anything? PySpark can run SparkSQL just fine

Comment: Because it is a long SQL case statement(20 lines). i would rather do it pragmatically using some logic.

Comment: You could use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when). Not sure how that handles multiple cases, though

Comment: you could write all of this as logic in a map function. have you tried that?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

These are few ways to write `If-Else` / `When-Then-Else` / `When-Otherwise` expression in `pyspark`.

**Sample dataframe**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)],['id','value'])

df.show()

#+---+-----+
#| id|value|
#+---+-----+
#|  1|    1|
#|  2|    2|
#|  3|    3|
#+---+-----+

#Desired Output:
#+---+-----+----------+
#| id|value|value_desc|
#+---+-----+----------+
#|  1|    1|       one|
#|  2|    2|       two|
#|  3|    3|     other|
#+---+-----+----------+
```

**Option#1**: `withColumn()` using when-otherwise

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.withColumn("value_desc",when(df.value == 1, 'one').when(df.value == 2, 'two').otherwise('other')).show()
```

**Option#2**: `select()` using when-otherwise

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.select("*",when(df.value == 1, 'one').when(df.value == 2, 'two').otherwise('other').alias('value_desc')).show()
```

**Option3:** `selectExpr()` using SQL equivalent CASE expression

```
df.selectExpr("*","CASE WHEN value == 1 THEN  'one' WHEN value == 2 THEN  'two' ELSE 'other' END AS value_desc").show()
```

SQL like expression can also be written in `withColumn()` and `select()` using [pyspark.sql.functions.expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) function. Here are examples.

**Option4:** `select()` using expr function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr 

df.select("*",expr("CASE WHEN value == 1 THEN  'one' WHEN value == 2 THEN  'two' ELSE 'other' END AS value_desc")).show()
```

**Option5:** `withColumn()` using expr function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr 

df.withColumn("value_desc",expr("CASE WHEN value == 1 THEN  'one' WHEN value == 2 THEN  'two' ELSE 'other' END AS value_desc")).show()
```

**Output:**

```
#+---+-----+----------+
#| id|value|value_desc|
#+---+-----+----------+
#|  1|    1|       one|
#|  2|    2|       two|
#|  3|    3|     other|
#+---+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 33):

Im not good in python. But will try to give some pointers of what I have done in scala.

> #### Question : `rdd.map` and then do some logic checks. Is that the right approach?

Its one approach.

[`withColumn` is another approach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

[`DataFrame.withColumn` method in pySpark supports adding a new column or replacing existing columns of the same name.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

In this context you have to deal with `Column`
   via - spark udf or when otherwise syntax

[for example :](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/column.html)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(df.name, F.when(df.age > 4, 1).when(df.age < 3, -1).otherwise(0)).show()


+-----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| name|CASE WHEN (age > 4) THEN 1 WHEN (age < 3) THEN -1 ELSE 0|
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------+
|Alice|                                                      -1|
|  Bob|                                                       1|
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(df.name, F.when(df.age > 3, 1).otherwise(0)).show()

+-----+---------------------------------+
| name|CASE WHEN (age > 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0|
+-----+---------------------------------+
|Alice|                                0|
|  Bob|                                1|
+-----+---------------------------------+
```

you can use udf instead of `when` `otherwise` as well.

Comment: if you are okay with answer! please accept as owner.

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)