# Issue Converting sql code into Pyspark code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert below sql code to pyspark data frame code not in spark.sql('code') code.

```
select * from table1 where 
(
case when clm1 in ('R','C', 'F') then l=1 
when clm1 in ('8','8-B') 
and (select coalesce(max (code),0) from table2 where clm2 = "XXX') = 0 then 1=2
else 1=2 end)
```

How to use case condition in where condition...

Comment: This shows some examples of using `case when` with pyspark:    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982135/apache-spark-dealing-with-case-statements

Comment: can you please share an input and output dataset - how it is looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming above is the working query-

```scala
df.where("case when clm1 in ('R','C', 'F') then l=1 when clm1 in ('8','8-B') and (select coalesce(max (code),0) from table2 where clm2 = "XXX') = 0 then 1=2 else 1=2 end")
```

Comment: What about if the sql is as below :  select * from table1 where 
(
case when clm1 in ('R','C', 'F') then l=1 
when clm1 in ('8','8-B') 
and (select coalesce(max (code),0) from table2 where clm2 = "XXX') = 0 then table.clm3=table2.clm4
else 1=2 end)