# I am trying to convert python code to pyspark but getting error as 'Row' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying below python code to convert in pyspark. Please let me know what's wrong in pyspark version of code:-

Original python version:-

```
for i in range(0,km_data.count()):

  if i==0:

     km_data['risk'].iloc[i]=not_lapsed+lapsed
      

  else:

    km_data['risk'].iloc[i]=km_data['risk'].iloc[i-1]-(km_data['lapsed'].iloc[i-1])-(km_data['censored'].iloc[i])
```

Pyspark version used:-

```
for i in range(0,km_data.count()):

  if i==0:

    km_data.collect()[i]['risk']=not_lapsed+lapsed

  else:

    km_data.collect()[i]['risk']=km_data.collect()[i-1]['risk']-(km_data.collect()[i-1]['lapsed'])-(km_data.collect()[i-1]['cencosred'])
```

Basically I am looking for equivalent of iloc in pyspark which can help me getting the results. Please ignore indentation issues as I have typed this code using mobile.

Comment: You want to share the sample input and output in Table format for a better visibility ?

Comment: @dsk, actually using collect() I am getting error as row object does not support assignment.

Comment: That is because you are assigning a value here    km_data.collect()[i]['risk']= ... try using when() and otherwise() combination , which is  nothing but if else in Python

Comment: @dsk could you please show me an example of using when and otherwise with loop?

Comment: Please follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982135/apache-spark-dealing-with-case-statements

Answer (score 0):

Collect() can be used here, and I can see you did the same-

```
X = df.collect()[0]['age']  
or 
X = df.collect()[0][1]  #row 0 col 1
```

is there anything other than you are looking for ?