# Create a boolean column and fill it if other column contains a particular string in Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark Dataframe.

I have a pyspark dataframe which has a column which contains value in below format

| Col1 |
| --- |
| a+ |
| b+ |
| a- |
| b- |

I want to create another boolean column (Col2). Value for this column will be true if Col1 is having + in its value else it will be False.

I tried below code after research on Googleverse but it gave  unexpected EOF while parsing error

```
DF = DF.withColumn("col2", F.when(DF.filter(DF.col1.like('+')), True).otherwise(False)
```

I also tried below code but that is also giving error Condition should be a column

```
df = DF.withColumn("col2", F.when(DF.filter("col1 like '%-%'")=="-", True).otherwise(False))
```

Please assist me on this

Comment: Don't think you need df.filter. DF.col1.like should be enough I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `filter` to scan each row of `col1`. You can just use the column's value inside `when` and try to match it with the `%+` literal that indicates that you are searching for a `+` character at the very end of the `String`.

```
DF.withColumn("col2", when(col("col1").like("%+"), true).otherwise(false))
```

This will result in the following DataFrame:

```
+----+-----+
|col1| col2|
+----+-----+
|  a+| true|
|  b+| true|
|  a-|false|
|  d-|false|
+----+-----+
```

You can study more about the `when`/`otherwise` functionality [here](https://beginnersbug.com/when-otherwise-in-pyspark-with-examples/) and [here](https://www.educba.com/pyspark-when/).

Comment: You're welcome. Please tick to accept the answer for other people to know that the issue is solved.

Comment: can you please tell me if i can check that the column name is present in the dataframe or not? the same query but only change is i need to check if the column is present or not.if yes that column should be added else null ..can you suggest solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Vikram, it seems like you want to base the above functionality within a condition. the answer given here should give you what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56291179/5644037

Comment: Hi @Coursal , The answer which you have suggested deals with the "column values". My requirement is to check the column name if it is present or not. For example in the solution which you have shared when column 'value' is present in a dataframe then that column should be returned to 'value_desc' if not 'null' should be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `+` is always at the end in your sample, I assume that's the pattern we can rely on, so the easier (and probably faster) solution is using [`endswith`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.endswith)

```py
df.withColumn('col2', F.col('col1').endswith('+')).show()

# +----+-----+
# |col1| col2|
# +----+-----+
# |  a+| true|
# |  b+| true|
# |  a-|false|
# |  b-|false|
# +----+-----+
```